# How to stop the adb process in Eclipse ADT?

Tags: android, eclipse, debugging, adb, adt

Essentially, I have finished developing and debugging my android application and I would like to disconnect my android device. However I cannot safely disconnected since the adb process is still running!

**How to systematically stop the adb process that Eclipse started?**
Simply killing the process is dirty and inelegant!

*Note: I am aware of [keeping my device charging mode](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9554086/2110869)*, however it does not solve the fact that the adb process is running when I disconnect my device (whether I keep it in charging mode or not)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't kill the adb server from Eclipse, simply because that feature has not been implemented in Eclipse ADT plugin.

This is from Android Official documentation on Eclipse ADT plugin:

> adb: Provides access to a device from your development system. Some
>   features of adb are integrated into ADT such as project installation
>   (Eclipse run menu), file transfer, device enumeration, and logcat
>   (DDMS). You must access the more advanced features of adb, such as
>   shell commands, from the command line.

Answer (score 1):

To stop the adb process you might want to kill the adb server through the following command on your command line,

/android-sdk/platform-tools/> adb kill-server

To start the adb Server you'll need to do the following,

adb start-server

Comment: Definitely does the job! But doesn't Eclipse have any built in feature?! It is almost hilarious that Eclipse spawns such processes that we have to manually kill!

Comment: I dont think there is a way to stop adb from eclipse. However the process starts when an instance of eclipse is opened.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `adb kill-server`

Visit this [link](http://android.okhelp.cz/how-quickly-restart-adb-exe-adb-server-android-emulator-example/) for further details..